# Java exception handling: catch an exception thrown by an external dependency module

Tags: java, exception, throw

I am calling from within a module A a class from a module B (which is just a dependency I can't modify): inside the class of the module B is been thrown a NullPointerException. I would need to catch this NullPointerException in the point where I'm calling this module B class.

Please note that the NullPointerException does not come out run time, but is explicitly thrown with a "**throw**"

Theoretically speaking, would I be able to do that?

Comment: Yes, just `try` - `catch` the `B` call in the `A` class.

Comment: Have you tried catching it? It is simple to check. From your explanation it should behave as any library from the class path. You can catch exceptions that belong to those libraries, right? It is little strange to catch NullPointerException in real world scenario though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java does not know about modules or whether you can modify them, so this works as usual:

If a statement throws an exception, it will be delivered to the first matching catch block of a caller. Therefore, if module B does not catch the exception, it will arrive at your catch block.